# CSS transform inheritance

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to change only one CSS transform attribute (namely translateY).
but in the animation, it changes the other functions (rotate, skew, etc.) too, is there a way to avoid it without giving the same values again?

Code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes leafAnim {
    to { -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);  }
}
.class {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg) skewX(-12deg) skewY(-14deg);
    -webkit-animation: cAnimation 1.5s ease infinite alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put

```
@-webkit-keyframes leafAnim {
    to { 
      -webkit-transform:translateY(-2px) rotate(-9deg) skewX(-12deg) skewY(-14deg);
    }
    .class {
      -webkit-animation: cAnimation 1.5s ease infinite alternate;
    }
```

You copy and paste anyway so why this question anyway ?:)

Comment: thats why I said "You copy and paste anyway so why this question anyway ?:)". And anwser is "no" I dont think so you can do it ""without giving the same values again?" but I can be wrong. Cheers